# Anybody know what the Magento API v2 SOAP XML call is to assign an attribute set to a product?

Tags: magento-1.8, api, soap, xml

How do I assign an attribute set to products via XML? Presently products are all created and assigned to the default attribute set..Here is the XML that I am using to create configurable products:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<soapenv:Header />
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:catalogProductCreate soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">93de69dab0c0ba19b00a328808ce3dasd8a</sessionId>
  <type xsi:type="xsd:string">configurable</type>
  <set xsi:type="xsd:string">4</set>
  <sku xsi:type="xsd:string">0001</sku>
  <productData xsi:type="urn:catalogProductCreateEntity">
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Example Product</name>
    <description xsi:type="xsd:string">Example Description.</description>
    <short_description>Example short description</short_description>
    <weight xsi:type="xsd:string">0.50</weight>
    <status xsi:type="xsd:string">2</status>
    <price>39.99</price>
    <visibility xsi:type="xsd:string">4</visibility>
    <tax_class_id xsi:type="xsd:string">2</tax_class_id>
    <category_ids xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
      <key>category_id</key>
      <value>60</value>
      <key>category_id</key>
      <value>7</value>
      <key>category_id</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </category_ids>
    <additional_attributes xsi:type="urn:catalogProductAdditionalAttributesEntity">
      <single_data xsi:type="urn:associativeArray" soapenc:arrayType="urn:associativeEntity[]">
        <associativeArray>
          <value>color</value>
        </associativeArray>
        <associativeArray>
          <value>size</value>
        </associativeArray>
      </single_data>
    </additional_attributes>
    <associated_skus xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
      <value>9214018662</value>
    </associated_skus>
    <associated_skus xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
      <value>9214018664</value>
    </associated_skus>
    <associated_skus xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
      <value>9214018658</value>
    </associated_skus>
    <associated_skus xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
      <value>9214018665</value>
    </associated_skus>
    <associated_skus xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
      <value>9214018663</value>
    </associated_skus>
    <associated_skus xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
      <value>9214018660</value>
    </associated_skus>
    <associated_skus xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
      <value>9214018659</value>
    </associated_skus>
    <associated_skus xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
      <value>9214018657</value>
    </associated_skus>
    </productData>
    <storeView xsi:type="xsd:string">1</storeView>
    </urn:catalogProductCreate>
   </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

old: Magento core doesn't support changing attribute sets of products.

While creating products, `attribute_set_id` should work.

To get the attribute sets, you can use `product_attribute_set.list`.

Comment: That is true. Maybe I did not articulate well, I am trying to assign a attribute set to products during product creation.